# SonarQube: Log to Console

Tags: c#, sonarqube

Is this rule applied to console applications? If yes, how can we log to the conosle then? Or why shouldn't you do it?
http://dist.sonarsource.com/plugins/csharp/rulesdoc/0.10.0-RC/S2228.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable this rule on Console Applications. Nevertheless, even for console applications, it can be a good idea to limit the number of `Console.WriteLine()` calls for instance to make it easier to later on change your application. For example, you don't want to see `Console.*` calls spread to the whole codebase, but see it perhaps contained in a single class. If that is the case, feel free to mark those issues as Won't Fix in SonarQube, to indicate that you have reviewed them and that they are expected and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you ca try to implement a sonar-project.properties file that would contain a sonar exclusions definition and you can exclude from Sonar scan the files containing console.log calls.

example:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/__tests__/**/*,**/*.js
```